# IHostedService Stop without any reason

Tags: c#, .net-core, kestrel

Could anyone explain to me why my server stopped for no reason?
below my IHostedService implementation:

```
public class HostServiceBox : IHostedService
{
        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                DomonutyBoxBusiness.StartBoxListening(); //STARTUP Box listening

                while (true)
                {
                    Logging.Info(DateTime.Now + " HostServiceBox Running");
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);
                }
            }, cancellationToken);
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Logging.Info(DateTime.Now + " StopAsync");

            // TODO implement a stop listening all boxes
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

Here is my log?

```
    .....
2/24/2018 8:31:27 PM HostServiceBox Running
2/24/2018 8:32:27 PM HostServiceBox Running
2/24/2018 8:33:27 PM HostServiceBox Running
2/24/2018 8:34:27 PM HostServiceBox Running  <------
2/25/2018 11:22:07 AM HostServiceBox Running <-----
2/25/2018 11:23:07 AM HostServiceBox Running
2/25/2018 11:24:07 AM HostServiceBox Running
2/25/2018 11:25:07 AM HostServiceBox Running
......
```

is look like on IIS with kestrel (.Net Core) my method slept ? Why?

Usualy my **while(true)** restart because i call the API. But **IHostedService** is a background task it's shouldnt stop right?

related post on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1332)

Comment: I could be wrong, but as far as I remember IIS able to stop website pool when there no activity on website and awake it when activity starts. You can check pool settings, there was something related this

Comment: Are you able to log something at startup and shutdown, to narrow down the cause? Is there anything interesting in `Event Viewer`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

User tym32167 is on the right track. This is mentioned in the documentation for `IHostedService` in the section on [deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice#deployment-considerations-and-takeaways):

> on IIS or a regular Azure App Service, your host can be shut down because of app pool recycles

IIS app pools have a default idle-timeout of 20 minutes, and they also have a default app pool recycle time of 29 hours. Typically you want to set the idle timeout to zero (disabled) and the recycle to a fixed time where it will do the least harm.

There's an interesting blog post about why they chose 29 hours [here](https://blogs.iis.net/owscott/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes) and it also covers idle timeout.

Also, if you happen to be deploying to Azure, that article linked earlier suggests other ways to deploy that will truly run full-time (containers, WebJobs, etc).

Comment: Is any other solution without change setting IIS (App Pool). I mean i want to keep default setting in IIS.

because if IIS is never recycle then it may catch more memory.

that's why I looking for other else this is ok